# cant install tensorflow-addons i have tensorflow version 2.8 and python 3.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-addons

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons

Comment: `Python 3.10` is very new version and many modules may not be ready for this version - authors may need some time to create modules for `3.10`. Better wait few months and use `3.9` or `3.8`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see that error message is because `tensorflow-addons` is in beta development and built only up to python 3.9

Please downgrade your python version to 3.9, that should do the trick (for any operating system).

After that, please run:
`pip install tensorflow-addons==0.15.0`

You should not see any uncompatibilities or error messages.